# Conversion of MIPS to %

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've been learning TSQL and need some help with a conversion CPU MIPS into PERCENTAGE.

I've built my code to get some data that I'm expecting. In addition to this, I want to add a column to my code which is to get the CPU%. I have a column that gives me TOTALCPU MIPS and want to use this in the code but in the form of percentage. Example, I have these values in my TOTAL CPU Column:

```
1623453.66897 
0 
0 
2148441.01573933 
3048946.946314
```

I want to convert these values into percentage and use them. I couldn't find much info on the internet.

Appreciate your response.

Comment: What would he corresponding percentages be?  What is the calculation?

Comment: To convert CPU MIPS into PERCENTAGE you need maximum available MIPS. It's not clear if you have that. If you do, what is so difficult about dividing the two numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have 5 numeric quantities (2 of them being zero) and you want to find the percentage that corresponds to each of them out of the addition of the five quantities.  Is it so?

To find the percentage of a particular number in the addition you multiply the number by 100 and divide by the addition, the result is the percentage that that number is in relation with the addition.

The sum: 6820841.631023

The percentage of the first number (of MIPS):

1623453.668970 * 100 / 6820841.631023 = 23.80136876 =>

23.80136876% is the percentage of CPU used by the first program.

To give the answer some SQL looking, refering to Mips_Table as the view/table that contains the MIPs data:

```
select mips, mips/totMips*100 Pct_CPU
from Mips_Table, 
    (select sum(mips) TotMips from Mips_Table) k
```